# Site.createPortalUser() - Email Confirmation

Tags: community, email, user

I have existing Contact records that need to be transitioned into Community Users.  I'm looking to use the Site.createPortalUser() method to create Community Users in an Apex Trigger.  I'd like to send an email with the username and password to the contact/user when this occurs.  What would be the best way to go about this?

I see that the Site.createPortalUser() method does support an email confirmation but I do not know what template this uses.  Does it use the email template you can configure in the Community Management menu?
[image: Community Management menu]

If I choose not to use the Site.createPortalUser() method to send the email confirmation, will the the email template configured in the Community Management menu be sent? Can that template include the username and password?

Comment: Why don't you just run a bulk job to convert your contacts and then reset their passwords? I'm not sure the reasoning behind a trigger here. If you did it all at once, everyone could get your branded email template with a one click link to login and change their password.

Comment: The thought behind a trigger was that this could then be used in the future to create a Communtiy User based a checkbox field on the Contact record.  Using the bulk job where would I configure the email template to send when the User is created? Is that in the code or in the Community Management menu?

Comment: But the end goal here is still pretty much the same. You want a way to convert all your existing contacts in mass and then have almost the same process happen on a per contact level going forward. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, that is accurate.

Comment: Ok sweet. I have some flows that manage all this kind of stuff in my org. Give me a bit and I'll see what I can get over to you that may help.

Comment: What is the count on contacts that you will be converting in your initial job?

Comment: It'd be around 35,000 contacts for the initial job